# How to have rails image tags display vertically

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to add social media links in my website using icons I have. I've got the images displaying, as well as having them clickable to open a new tab to their corresponding website. However, they are displaying horizontally right next to each other, and I'd like them to be in a list so to speak. I've tried using the  tag, as well as put them in their own articles, paragraphs, nothing I do seems to work. any help would be appreciated. Here's the code I have thus far

```
<body>
  <div>
    <a href="https://twitter.com/tavernsavepoint" target= "_blank">
      <%= image_tag("Twitter icon.png", display: 'inline-block', style: 'margin-top: 30px;') %>
    </a>
  </div>
</body>

<body>
  <div>
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/tavernsavepoint/" target= "_blank">
      <%= image_tag("facebook icon.png", display: 'inline-block', style: 'margin-top: 30px;') %>
    </a>
  </div>
</body>

<body>
  <div>
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/tavernsavepoint/" target= "_blank">
      <%= image_tag("facebook icon.png", display: 'inline-block', style: 'margin-top: 30px;') %>
    </a>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: is each one really wrapped in a `<body></body>` tag? Is this the HTML exactly as you have it?  Also, could you share the css you have working on this if there is any?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly how I have it currently. It didn't originally have the body tags, I just tried that to get them to stack. And no, I do not have a CSS with it.

Comment: O.k. so first I would refrain from trying things like that just to get it to work.  The easiest way I have found to figure something like this out is find an example and then use your browser's inspector to view the styles on it.  At this point it would be quite hard to give an answer as it really depends on the HTML of the whole page. Is this just local or is there a page that can be viewed?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a list. If you don't want to use css but are happy with inline styles I would recommend list-style: none on the ul element to remove bullet points.

```
 <ul style="list-style:none;">
  <li>
    <a href="https://twitter.com/tavernsavepoint" target= "_blank">
      <%= image_tag("Twitter icon.png", display: 'inline-block', style: 'margin-top: 30px;') %>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/tavernsavepoint/" target= "_blank">
      <%= image_tag("facebook icon.png", display: 'inline-block', style: 'margin-top: 30px;') %>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/tavernsavepoint/" target= "_blank">
      <%= image_tag("facebook icon.png", display: 'inline-block', style: 'margin-top: 30px;') %>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```